# How to benchmark a SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql-server, database, benchmarking

I'd like to know the standard way to benchmark a SQL Sever Query, preferably I'd like to know about the tools that come with SQL Server rather than 3rd Party tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set showplan_text on 
will show you the execution plan (to see it graphically use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> (sql 2000) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (sql 2005 +)

set statistics IO on
will show you the reads

set statistics time on
will show you the elapsed time

Comment: Run `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` before your query to clear the caches without restarting the SQL Server. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-dropcleanbuffers-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Profiler.

For .NET applications, filter that Application name by '.NET%' and you'll omit other extraneous queries.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the execution plan. From here you can see where all the time is being spent in your particular query. Eg. 85% of the time is spent table scanning a particular table, can you put an index on that table to improve it? etc etc.