# Query benchmarking

Tags: sql-server, benchmarking

### Preamble

I have a hypothesis about the performance difference between using the native SQL aggregate functions and the aggregates supplied in SSIS (database will crush SSIS). I'd like to develop an empirical process for testing that.

For initial testing, my sole concern is execution speed. Later iterations will cover cpu and memory costs.

To accomplish this, I've built out a small table (100M rows) and want to capture the difference in timings. I'm planning on doing it all within an SSIS package by comparing the timings of OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute.

The first data flow will take the form of `SELECT * FROM TABLE` while the latter would be `SELECT Aggregate(col1) FROM TABLE`

[image: SSIS Aggregate] vs 
[image: Database Aggregate]

Similar questions but not what I was looking for

- [SQL Server Queries - Baseline and Benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442699/sql-server-queries-baseline-and-benchmarking)
- [How to benchmark a SQL Server Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858/how-to-benchmark-a-sql-sever-query)

### tl;dr;

To make the evaluations as even as possible, should I

- flush the cache between steps
- warm the cache by executing the queries beforehand
- something else

If the decision is to flush, is [`dbcc freeproccache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) sufficient or do I need to [`dbcc dropcleanbuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I think you really want to clear the page cache between runs.

If it were me I would run something like:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
CHECKPOINT
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

The `FREEPROCCACHE` only clears the plan cache, and has nothing to do with data pages.

The `CHECKPOINT` will flush all dirty pages to disk.

The `DROPCLEANBUFFERS` will clear the buffer pool of data pages.

I would also consider `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET_STATISTICS TIME ON` for anything run in SSMS.